# Retrieve speed and number of Lanes in Google Maps API, OSM data or any other stream?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, transportation

Is it possible to return the posted speed and number of lanes of a highway segment using Google Maps API, OSM data, or any other stream (paid for or free)?

Comment: Specifically for OSM, are you looking for a way using an OSM API or downloaded OSM data ?

Comment: @Will. I'm open to both, preferably be able to use the API; however, I have no issues whatsoever if I can download the data to myserver and use that

Comment: from the OSM website (http://www.openstreetmap.org/) you can always export the area of interest in XML and take out the info on the type of road and speed limit. but i am not sure this is how you want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I will give you a method using downloaded OSM data, as the API is designed for editing and not for read-only. You will find more details on this on the [API usage policy page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy) of the OSM wiki. If you really want to use an API, you can look at the read-only APIs like the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). Several other methods could also work, depending on how you will use this data and which tools you like most.

- Download OSM data for you area of interest. Use [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) if the area is big, or the [OSM website](http://www.osm.org) export tab if your area is small (a city or less).
- Put all this data in PostGIS :

  - Install [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) and find the default.style file (on Ubuntu : /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style)
  - Copy this default.style, save it as yourdefault.style and edit it to add the following lines so you can retrieve the [lanes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3alanes) and [maxspeed](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maxspeed) from OSM:

    ```
    way   lanes        text         linear
    way   maxspeed         text         linear
    ```
  - Run the following (this is for Ubuntu but should be very similar on Windows):

    ```
    sudo su postgres
    createdb gis
    psql -d gis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
    psql gis -c "ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO postgres"
    psql gis -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO postgres"
    osm2pgsql -s --style /path/yourdefault.style -W -U postgres -d gis /file/path/toosm/fileorpbf/name.osm
    ```
- You can now run any query you want on the *gis* database to get the maxspped and number of lanes of a road segment

**Important note**: this is a technical method, but there is no guarantee that the speed and number of lanes are present in OSM for the highways you are interested in.